# Do I need to submit for facebook app review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

My app needs to post as a user or one their pages. So to my understanding I need these scopes "publish_actions manage_pages publish_pages". It would seem that I need to submit for review to get them. Is it absolutely necessary that I do this or is there some exception to the rule. For example, using an older version of the graph api API, a specfifc SDK (php etc), older version of Oauth, wordpress plugin etc. Just want to make sure I need to before making the effort to go through that process.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about Login Review can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Downgrading to an older API version is not possible, the lowest API version is the latest one by the time you created the App. You can´t avoid Login Review by using another API version or SDK, but permissions work without review for everything with a role in the App.

If you want to create an app just for yourself, there is no need for Login Review. If you want to go public with your App, you have to go through Login Review.